# Learn Python the Hard Way Ex26: Not Getting Expected Result

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

```
    def break_words(stuff):
        """This function will break up words for us."""
        words = stuff.split(' ')
        return words

    def sort_words(words):
        """Sorts the words."""
        return words.sort()

    def print_first_word(words):
        """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
        word = words.pop(0)
        print word

    def print_last_word(words):
        """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
        word = words.pop(-1)
        print word

    def sort_sentence(sentence):
        """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
        words = break_words(sentence)
        return sort_words(words)

    def print_first_and_last(sentence):
        """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
        words = break_words(sentence)
        print_first_word(words)
        print_last_word(words)

    def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
        """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
        words = sort_sentence(sentence)
        print_first_word(words)
        print_last_word(words)


    print "Let's practice everything."
    print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

    poem = """
    \tThe lovely world
    with logic so firmly planted
    cannot discern \n the needs of love
    nor comprehend passion from intuition
    and requires an explanation
    \n\t\twhere there is none.
    """


    print "--------------"
    print poem
    print "--------------"

    five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 5
    print "This should be five: %s" % five

    def secret_formula(started):
        jelly_beans = started * 500
        jars = jelly_beans / 100
        crates = jars / 100
        return jelly_beans, jars, crates


    start_point = 10000
    beans, jars, crates == secret_formula(start-point)

    print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
    print "We'd have %d jeans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)

    start_point = start_point / 10

    print "We can also do that this way:"
    print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_point)


    sentence = "All good\tthings come to those who wait."

    words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
    sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words)

    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
    print_first_word(sorted_words)
    print_last_word(sorted_words)
    sorted_words = ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_sorted_words

    print_first_and_last(sentence)

    print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
```

This is my updated code. I figured there were some logical errors in the code, but I updated it to try to start over since I think I completely messed up the code. The first thing I should mention is that I have a syntax error in line 77, which seems impossible to identify because I would think that, to begin with, if I assign a string to a variable then it should not give a syntax error. I'm guessing its on another line.

I started over to try and do everything from scratch. This is getting ridiculous. I think what I have to find next are the logic errors that are left. Tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorted method isn't correct.  In python, somelist.sort() sorts the list in place and returns None, so you end up erasing your list.  You can either do words = sorted(words) or just words.sort() but doing words = words.sort() ends up setting words to None.

Also, your split words is most likely not correct.  Doing stuff[0] gets the first string in your sentences array; casting it to a list returns a list of the letters with each letter an element of the list.  Given how you defined sentence, you already have a split sentence; if you had done sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog), your split words could do sentence.split(" ") to break it into words.

Lastly, doing pop mutates the list; your list is ["A","l","l"] and so after 3 calls to get_first or get_last, you've now popped all the elements off so the 4th pop will, as you are seeing, return empty list.  I don't know if this is desired behavior; if not, you can do words[0] to get the first without mutating and words[-1] to get the last.

Comment: How to pop without mutating? I want it to return the last element. Hmmm.

Comment: As mentioned, val = words[-1] assigns the last element in words to val.

Comment: How to not pop all of the elements off?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was trying to get rid of all of the errors in the exercise. I think I'm going to reedit my thread since I started from scratch with fixing the bugs. The point of the exercise is to fix all of the bugs so it compiles without error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was supposed to comment out lines 79-91. That was it! I did everything else perfectly! :D